# Getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" on a file that exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to use the file "a.png" whereas if I run the following code on my Python file

```
print(pathlib.Path("a.png"))
```

Using IDLE of Geany, the output is true, however if I go to Windows command line and try:

> 'python "pythonfilelocation.py"'

The output will be false, I would like to know why, and how can it be fixed. 
I am uving Python version Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why, the thing is:
I was on the folder

> C:\Windows\system32> when i was trying to execute the file, since I didnt give the file location in Python a full name, it probably tried  to find the file 
>   C:\Windows\system32\a.png

I had to go to the folder i was working on, to make it work straight.